# similarity proof

Tags: geometry

> Prove  that if the vertical angle of a straight line which cuts the base,  the rectangle contained by the segments of the base with the square on the line segment which bisects the angle and meeting at base
>
> i.e. , if $\angle ABC=\angle ACB$  i.e. $AB =AC$ and $AD$ is the angle bisector
> then prove that
> $AB\times AC=BD\times DC+AD^2$

Comment: This text is unparseable: "if the vertical angle of a straight line which cuts the base".  Not only is the reference to "base" unclear, the hypothesis is not a properly formed clause.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

Notice that by angle bisector theorem,

$$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BD}{DC}$$

Now,as $\frac{AB}{AC}=1,$ we have $BD=DC$.

Also,by congruence,you can prove that,$\angle ADB=\angle ADC=90^0$.

So,$$AB^2=AD^2+BD^2$$

$$\implies AB\times AB=BD\times BD+AD^2$$

As,$AB=AC$ and $BD=DC$(as $\triangle ABD\cong\triangle ACD$.)

So, we can say,$ AB\times AC=BD\times DC+AD^2$ (Proved).

Comment: @tamajitbanerjee thanks...looking forward to your next question...

Comment: Why the downvote???!